# Android Change Layout from SurfaceView

Tags: android, layout, surfaceview

I am making an app with a login screen which then goes to a surfaceview where the game is played. The problem is that the user can be logged out while playing and I need to be able to return the user to the login screen. How would I do this?

I've tried adding this to the surfaceview, but it doesn't do anything:

`((Activity)getContext()).setContentView(R.layout.login);`

EDIT:

Issue is solved, here is the code I added in surfaceview:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getContext(), BattleLogin.class);
        ((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent,loginResult);
```

It may be important to mention to, don't forget to add the new activity to the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try creating an Intent to start a new Activity to handle user login? It would leave the previous Activity dedicated to the SurfaceView paused in the stack while the user interacts with the new screen.

You can use `startActivityForResult()` which is detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) anywhere in your SurfaceView Activity to obtain status information like successful login or something when your login Activity finishes.

Comment: I still don't see how to call this from surfaceview. The example is calling another activity from within the activity itself. I need to call it from surfaceview. When I try to do it from surfaceview, I get this: The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type Battle

Comment: I did some more work with your option as I don't like to "Hack" like Sam Quest suggested. I did get it to work. For everyone else, this is the code: 
   Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setClass(getContext(), BattleLogin.class);
   ((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent,loginResult);

Answer (score 0):

will not a alert dialog with a

```
Login Name:
Password:
```

work. the user should be able to enter credentials and continue.

maybe a save credentials should enable the user to auto login

```
using a progress dialog
```

while the game is paused.

**UPDATE**

the errors associated to the dialog may be because of UI thread issues.

but her is a quick hack

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/my_dialog"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="**visible|gone**"
    >
        <your loging layout comes here />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this will float above the surface. but you need to freeze the surface (pause you game) and also this layout should not hide the surface totally.

Comment: I still don't understand how to call it from surfaceview. Or I would at least need to be able to pass a variable to the main activity and finish the surfaceview so that the activity knows what layout to show next, but I can't find anything on how to switch from surfaceview to the main activity. I get all sorts of errors if I try to open a dialog in surfaceview.